# How to hide root folders from desktop? (like: Downloads, Videos, Music, ...)

Tags: directory, root, .desktop

[Here are the folders](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5Koo.jpg)

I tried much time and when I deleted folders from the desktop, the folders could be deleted from the main folder

Comment: Maybe I have to change my desktop folder path, how can I do it?

Comment: Please clarify what specific steps you've taken to remedy this problem. "Tried much time" is too vague and offers no support to anyone trying to recreate your problem.

Comment: I don't remember exactly (since I am not using ubuntu gnome desktop) but I think there is option for display/desktop settings in the setting menu where you can select which folders appear on your desktop.

Comment: please, could you [edit] your question showing the result of the command `cat ~/.config/user-dirs.dirs` ?

Comment: My theory is that, for unknown reasons to me, your Home folder is considered by the system as your Desktop folder.

Answer (score 0):

You defined your home folder to be your DESKTOP folder, so anything in your home folder currently is shown on the desktop. That may have happened after you have deleted the Desktop folder from your home folder.

To repair to the default setup, run following command in the terminal or in the Run prompt (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>):

```
xdg-user-dirs-update --force
```

This eventually will recreate special directories (e.g Desktop, Music, Video) in case they were deleted. Log out and then back in, and only files in the Desktop folder will show up on your desktop.